# Custom URL value from Gridview to other models yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        //'company-id',
        //'company-name',
        'department_name',
        'table_title',
        'entry_status',


        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
         'template' => '{create}',
         'buttons' => [
            'create' => function($url,$model){
                return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', $url, ['title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Entry Data'),]);    
            }]],
              ],
]); ?>
```

I want to make url in action column which every rows in this gridview has specific link to a specific model. For example: row 1 accessing url create/1 contains a table from a certain model. row 2 accessing url create/2 contains another table from another model. How could I do That?

Comment: Do you want to have 2 links right?

Comment: i want to have more than 2 links. I want to have specific link for every row